# Rails + Devise: How do I get an error message if password is not changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Devise for authentication. I want to have users the ability to change their passwords - so I have added this action to my controller:

```
def update_password
    if current_user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
      sign_in(current_user, bypass: true)
      redirect_to settings_path, notice: "Your password has been updated!"
    else
      current_user.errors.each do |err|
        puts "-> #{err.inspect}"
      end
      redirect_to settings_path, alert: "Problem: #{current_user.errors.inspect}"
    end
  end
```

If a user enters the right current password and the new password (plus its confirmation), then the password is changed - that's good.

However, when there's a problem, such as the new password + its confirmation is not matched, or if the entered current password is not correct, or if eg. the new password is not long enough - then it fails, that's good as well.

However, I'd want to display to users why the password has not been changed - how do I find out the reason for not changing the password? Where do I find the error messages?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just out of interest ... why are you writing this yourself and not using the existing password-change feature provided with Devise?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to validate some of these on the controller level and manually like the confirmation of the new password and the old password with a simple `if the did not match` then redirect_back and flash and error (it would be nice also to have a small JS script to evaluate this instead of waiting for a request to come to the controller but also keep the validation in the controller)

and for the old password confirmation, you will need to use `Devise::Encryptor.compare(klass, hashed_password, password)` and also raise a error manually then go on to storing a new password and check if the record did save normally

```rb
def update_password
    old_password = devise_parameter_sanitizer.require(:old_password)
    new_password = devise_parameter_sanitizer.require(:new_password)
    new_password_confirmation = devise_parameter_sanitizer.require(:new_password_confirmation)

    if new_password != new_password_confirmation
       redirect_to settings_path, alert: "NEW PASSWORD DO NOT MATCH"    
    end

    if Devise::Encryptor.compare(User, current_user.encrypted_password, old_password)
       redirect_to settings_path, alert: "SAME OLD PASSWORD ERROR!"    
    end 

    if current_user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
        redirect_to settings_path, notice: "Your password has been updated!"
    else
        redirect_to settings_path, alert: person.errors.full_messages.to_sentences 
    end
end
```